# A mechanism to include site title in every page, but not in <title> element

Tags: seo, page

Each site can have a name. For example, site x. Each page also can have a name (or a title) that should appear in `<title>` tag in the header. However, many websites out there use the combination `site name - page name` to provide the value for `<title>` tag. I find it a little far from being **semantic**. On the other hand, if you only include page title in `<title>` tag, search engines won't find your site by its name. For example, if your site's name is **Example Site** and you don't include it in page titles, then if you search for **Example Site**, you won't find your site in SERPs.

Thus I'm searching for a mechanism to both include **site title** (not page title) in every page, and also only include **page title** in `<title>` tag to get more semantic results.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `Page title - site title` instead of the other way around (like this site and millions of others do). It makes listings in search results for the page title keywords much more meaningful, and still allows your pages to rank for your site's title.

Comment: Good suggestion @Nick. But do we have any other mechanism to include site title separately?

Comment: @Saeed Can you explain what do you mean by 'include site title separately'?

Comment: I wonder if there is anything like `<meta name='site-title' content='Thought Results' />` which is more cleaner than mixing everything up in one element named `<title>`.

Comment: @Saeed There's no `site-title` meta tag. You could simply omit the site title altogether from your `<title>` tags, then put it in an `<h1>` tag on every page (you may already have this), but there's nothing wrong with having both the page and site title in your `<title>` tags. It's often useful for users to see the site title in search results. Again, I suggest using `Page title - site title` on subpages, and simply `Site title` on the homepage.

Comment: The site title is your logo, or somewhere in your header. Search engines are smart enough to know your site title and do need you to include it in every page title. The H1 tag is intented to be different for every page and should not be used for the site title.

Comment: @donaldthe Actually, Google recommends that you brand your title tag with your site name in their [Webmaster guidelines.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624) Agree that the leading `h1` or `h2` tag should be different for every page if possible.

Comment: @Nick, it does mention including your site title, but not in the context of the OP question, it does not say it is a recommend best practice. What is does recommend, from your link "Avoid repeated or boilerplate titles. It’s important to have distinct, descriptive titles for each page on your site." "About Us", "Privacy", "FAQ" Pages it makes sense to include the site name in the title tag, but if a website is more than a few pages then the site name in the title is a waste of valuable real estate.

Comment: @donaldthe That's an interesting point of view. I'm not sure I agree, though. It's worth noting that Wikipedia uses a 'boilerplate' title, as does the New York Times, The Guardian, and all Stack Exchange sites. Perhaps they think that seeing a familiar name in search results increases click-through. If it really was a waste of valuable real estate, maybe these sites would have dropped their name from their title tags by now.